# JSF updates view just on second request

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm running out of ideas about how to fix this problem, this is what happens: when I click a button that should update my view (through ajax) the server-side code is correctly executed, but the view is not updated. It is updated with the values of the last ajax request just when I make a second ajax request. It happens for every ajax action in my page, meaning that everything on the view is always showing old data. How old? 1 request old, always.

Digging into the problem I found some possible causes, for that, in the next lines, i'll explain in more details what I want to do.

I have a list of events, each event happens in a date. My page shows 12 calendars, one for each month, these calendars objective is to show the events happening in each day of the month. Besides the calendar I also have a panel to change the year and a dialog. The dialog is opened everytime the user clicks a date in the calendar. Through the dialogue it's possible to add a new event, remove the clicked event and edit the clicked event.

Each calendar is an instance of my custom component "Calendar" and it always receive a month, a year and a list of events as parameters. The list of events is passed through the method "getEvents(int month)" in my managedBean.

My ajax calls are:

- NextYear(): increment year in one in my managedBean, recalculate
  events. After completition, update my 12 calendar components.
- PreviousYear(): similar to nextYear.
- updateEvent(): update or create (if non-existent) the clicked event.
  Recalculate list of events. After completion update the calendars in
  view.
- cancelEvent(): cancel the event, remove it from the list of events.
  After completion update view.

As I said before, everything is done correctly, but the update. The update triggered by an ajax request is just done on the next ajax request.

To investigate what was going on I put printlns in the method "getEvents(int month)" to know when it was getting called and what events it was finding.

For my surprise, getEvents is called in every ajaxCall, and it doesn't matter if the ajax call updates the calendar or not. Always, before executing the server-side method, getEvents is called for the 12 calendars.

My conclusion was: the update is happening before the ajax request completion. To confirm that I wrote some printlns (and flushs) in the ajax methods. The getEvents do get called before any ajax method is completed. I think when update is called by JSF, it uses the values got before the method execution, not the new ones, what causes the view to be always one request late.

Have someone ever seen a problem like this? Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Edit: The code is complicated. To simplify things I reduced the problem to the "change year" requirement. If I remove everything else, the problem persists.

My view:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="components" name="calendar/aqua/calendar.css"  />
<link href="css/event_calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="year" value="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" />
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{managementEventCalendar.preRender()}" />
</f:metadata>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <!-- update the url parameter "year" according to the managed bean -->
  $(document).ready(function(){
    updateUrlParameter('year', #{managementEventCalendar.year});
  });
</script>

<p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" life="#{initParam['primefaces.growl.life']}" widgetVar="growlWidgetVar" />

<!-- just a title, irrelevant -->                  
<comp:management_title image="imgs/title_image_eventcalendar.png" title="#{msg['title.eventcalendar']}" description="#{msg['description.eventcalendar']}" styleClass="event" />

<!-- form to change the year -->
<h:form>
  <p class="text-center year-block">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-w" actionListener="#{managementEventCalendar.previousYear()}" update="@form :calendar" oncomplete="updateUrlParameter('year', #{managementEventCalendar.year - 1});" />
    <h:outputText styleClass="year-title" value="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" />
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-e" actionListener="#{managementEventCalendar.nextYear()}" update="@form :calendar" oncomplete="updateUrlParameter('year', #{managementEventCalendar.year + 1});" />
  </p>
</h:form>

<!-- Grid of calendars (12, one for each month) -->
<h:panelGrid id="calendar" columns="3" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom: 15px"
                             columnClasses="calendar-column left, calendar-column center, calendar-column right">
                <comp:calendar month="0" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(0)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="1" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(1)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="2" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(2)}" />

                <comp:calendar month="3" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(3)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="4" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(4)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="5" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(5)}" />

                <comp:calendar month="6" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(6)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="7" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(7)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="8" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(8)}" />

                <comp:calendar month="9" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(9)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="10" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(10)}" />
                <comp:calendar month="11" year="#{managementEventCalendar.year}" styleClass="espacamento_vertical" disablePast="false" theme="aqua" 
                               type="edition" eventDates="#{managementEventCalendar.getEvents(11)}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Some explanation about the component "calendar": disablePast and theme are cosmetic. "type = edition" means the calendar cells will be selectable. How selection works is not relevant since we're considering just the case where we want to change the year. I removed all the code concerning the event selection, edition and cancellation. All problems persisted.

See below the code of the component "calendar".

```
<composite:interface componentType="calendar">
            <composite:attribute name="month" type="java.lang.Integer" required="true" />
            <composite:attribute name="year" type="java.lang.Integer" required="true" />
            <composite:attribute name="eventDates" type="java.util.List" required="false" />
            <composite:attribute name="style" required="false" />
            <composite:attribute name="styleClass" required="false" />
            <composite:attribute name="disablePast" required="false" default="true" />
            <composite:attribute name="theme" required="false" default="rose" />
            <composite:attribute name="type" required="false" default="tooltip" />
            <composite:attribute name="eventManager" type="com.ae.client.web.management.EventManager" required="false" />
            <composite:attribute name="onselect" required="false" />
            <composite:attribute name="update" required="false" />
        </composite:interface>
        <composite:implementation>
            <h:outputScript library="components" name="calendar/calendar.js" target="head" />

            <c:set var="disabled" value="#{cc.attrs.disablePast and cc.isPastMonth()}" />

            <div class="calendar-component">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="254px" style="#{cc.attrs.style}"
                       class="calendar-table month_#{cc.attrs.month} #{disabled ? 'disabled' : ''} #{cc.attrs.type} #{cc.attrs.styleClass}">

                    <!-- Month name and week days -->
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="#{cc.numberOfWeeks + 1}" class="month">
                            <h:graphicImage library="components" alt="#{cc.getMonthName()}"
                                            name="calendar/#{cc.attrs.theme}/#{msg.locale}/month_#{disabled ? 'disabled_' : ''}#{cc.attrs.month}.png" />
                        </th>
                        <th class="week">D</th>
                        <th class="week">S</th>
                        <th class="week">T</th>
                        <th class="week">Q</th>
                        <th class="week">Q</th>
                        <th class="week">S</th>
                        <th class="week">S</th>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- Month days -->
                    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.calendar}" var="week">
                        <tr>
                            <ui:repeat value="#{week}" var="day">
                                <td class="#{(day.isToday() ? 'today' : '')} #{(empty (day.events)) ? '' : 'event'} #{(day.dayOfMonth eq 0) ? '' : 'selectable'}">
                                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="relative" rendered="#{not (day.dayOfMonth eq 0)}">
                                        <h:outputText class="day-of-month" value="#{day.dayOfMonth}" />

                                        <!-- events in the day -->
                                        <ui:repeat value="#{day.events}" var="eventDate">
                                            <div class="event-data">
                                                <h:outputText class="id" value="#{eventDate.event.id}" />
                                                <span class="name">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{eventDate.event.name}" />
                                                    <h:outputText value=" - #{eventDate.description}" rendered="#{not empty(eventDate.description) and eventDate.event.eventDates.size() gt 1}" />
                                                </span>
                                                <h:outputText  class="status" value="#{eventDate.event.status}" />
                                                <h:outputText class="time" value="#{eventDate.date}">
                                                    <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{msg['date.timezone']}" pattern="#{msg['time.format']}" type="time" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </div>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </td>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </table>
            </div>
        </composite:implementation>
```

My managed bean code is simple, I analyze the url parameter "year" in a pre-render event and  populate my collection of events when getEvents(int month) is first called. The collection of events is actually a map relating a month (0-11) to a list of event dates (EventDate). An Event can happen in multiple dates (eventDates), each eventDate has a date and a short description. To go to the previous year, i call the method previousYear(). See some managedBean code below:

```
    public void preRender(){
            GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
            if (year == 0) year = today.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateEventCollection() {
            eventMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<EventDate>>();
            Iterator<Event> eventIterator = eventRepository.findNotCanceledByYear(year).iterator();
            while (eventIterator.hasNext()){
                Event e = eventIterator.next();
                Iterator<EventDate> dateIterator = e.getEventDates().iterator();
                while (dateIterator.hasNext()){
                    EventDate date = dateIterator.next();
                    GregorianCalendar day = new GregorianCalendar();
                    day.setTime(date.getDate());
                    int month = day.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
                    List<EventDate> eventsInMonth = eventMap.get(month);
                    if (null == eventsInMonth){
                        eventsInMonth = new ArrayList<EventDate>();
                    }
                    eventsInMonth.add(date);
                    eventMap.put(month, eventsInMonth);
                }
            }
        }

    public List<EventDate> getEvents(int month){
            if (null == eventMap) updateEventCollection();
            List<EventDate> result = eventMap.get(month);
            if (null == result) result = new ArrayList<EventDate>();
            System.out.println("*** getting events of month " + month + ". " + result.size() + " dates were found.");
            System.out.flush();
            return result;
        }

public void nextYear(){
        year++;
        updateEventCollection();
    }

    public void previousYear(){
        year--;
        updateEventCollection();
    }
```

I hope it helps.

To describe my problem, specifically in the "change year" requirement: if the page is loaded in 2013 and I click the button "previous", the text representing the year is correctly updated to 2013, the calendars also seem to get updated, but with the same values I had before (2013), it's like it was not updated at all. When I click again, the year text is updated to 2011, but the calendar shows 2012. If i click again, and again, the calendar will always show the result of the previous request.

---

edit: after some digging it seems the problem lies in the utilization of , I have no idea about why it would cause such problem, but when I remove the following portion of the component's code, every variable is successfully updated into the view.

```
<!-- Month days -->
                    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.calendar}" var="week">
                        <tr>
                            <ui:repeat value="#{week}" var="day">
                                <td class="#{(day.isToday() ? 'today' : '')} #{(empty (day.events)) ? '' : 'event'} #{(day.dayOfMonth eq 0) ? '' : 'selectable'}">
                                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="relative" rendered="#{not (day.dayOfMonth eq 0)}">
                                        <h:outputText class="day-of-month" value="#{day.dayOfMonth}" />
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </td>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>
```

If I remove the second ui:repeat the problem continues, if I remove both the problem goes away, what makes me think it has something to do with the iteration over "cc.calendar". The variable cc.calendar has no particular problem, since to make the tests, after removing the , I print the following in the view:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.year}" /><br />
<h:outputText value="#{cc.calendar.size()}" /><br />
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.eventDates.size()}" /><br />
```

The value of cc.calendar.size() shows that everything gets correctly updated in the correct time. If I let these "prints" in the code and restore the ui:repeats, the values printed by  is wrong, it gets updated just if I make another ajax request, being always one request late.

It seems the problem is exclusively the ui:repeat tag, and I have no idea about how to fix it. I tried c:forEach, same problem.

Comment: Can you post some code please.

Comment: Without any code I'm just poking in the dark but this caught my attention **For my surprise, getEvents is called in every ajaxCall, and it doesn't matter if the ajax call updates the calendar or not** It sounds to me like you chose the wrong `event` for your ajax when `getEvents` is being called. But like I said, I might be missing the mark completely.

Comment: I just posted some code ;)

Comment: If you think there's important code missing, please say, I'll post it.

Comment: I did some more digging and I discovered all variables get correctly updated on ajax calls, unless maps. I have two maps and neither of them gets recalculated (getMap()) when "update" is requested. The values used to update the view are always the last values calculated, which, for some reason, are calculated just before the ajax call.

Comment: Phew lol. That's a lot. I'll start digging.

Comment: This is bizarre, it seems <ui:repeat> is causing the problem...

Comment: It sure is a lot, no need to dig into this. I'll try to make a new project reproducing the problem in smaller scale. If I succeed I'll post a more focused question and code tomorrow (I'll post the link here). Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: It's no problem. I'll look anyway and if I have something I'll let you know.

Comment: Here's the new question, it's also big, but much more focused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330771/ajax-view-updates-doesnt-work-properly-in-custom-components-with-dedicated-java

Comment: Ok, I'll go have a look.