# JSF updates view with previous request result

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

After updating my project to use Primefaces 5.2, from 5.0, all my updates are showing the data of one request old. If I click a commandLink twice, the first click doesn't do anything in client side, server does the action/actionListener and the request comes with previous data without changes, the second click updates with the result of the first request. Always the server does the job but JSF doesn't.

With PrimeFaces 5.0, all works fine.

Here is my pom.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <description>Project Foo</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jboss-3rd-party-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jboss.bom>8.1.0.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- PRIMEFACES JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-mobile</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OMNIFACES JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOG4j -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FILE UPLOAD -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL EXPRESSION -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LIQUIBASE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WILDFLY 8.1.0 STUFS -->
                ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <profiles>
        ...
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And here's an example of my jsf code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" template="/sistema/template.xhtml">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>

    <ui:define name="center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="block-web block-color primary">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="header">
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="actions">
                            <a class="minimize" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h3>
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Gerenciamento de Roles
                        </h3>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <div class="porlets-content">
                        <h:form id="cadastro">
                            <div class="align-center m-b-10 btn-toolbar">
                                <p:commandLink oncomplete="showModal('#formCadastro')" update=":formCad" styleClass="btn btn-labeled btn-primary">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="" target="#{roleController.selected}" />
                                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                                    <h:outputText value=" Adicionar" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink oncomplete="showModal('#form-del')" styleClass="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span>
                                    <h:outputText value=" Remover" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink onclick="showModal('#atualizar')" oncomplete="removeModal('#atualizar');" styleClass="btn btn-labeled btn-default" actionListener="#{roleController.update()}">
                                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
                                    <h:outputText value=" Atualizar" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </div>

                            <p:dataTable id="tabela" resizableColumns="true" var="role" value="#{roleController.list}" selectionMode="single" sortMode="single" selection="#{roleController.selected}"
                                rowKey="#{role.id}" paginator="true" rows="20" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" paginatorPosition="top" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado"
                                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} de {totalPages} ({totalRecords})" filteredValue="#{roleController.filtered}" widgetVar="tabelaUsuario"
                                sortBy="#{role.descricao.toUpperCase()}">

                                <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" oncomplete="showModal('#formCadastro')" update=":formCad :cadastro" />

                                <p:column headerText="CÓDIGO" width="10%" sortBy="#{role.id}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{role.id}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="NOME" width="90%" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{role.descricao}" sortBy="#{role.descricao.toUpperCase()}" filterStyleClass="width-100p">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{role.descricao}" />
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- pop-ups -->
        <ui:include src="./cadRole.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And finnaly, controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RoleController extends PesquisaController<Role> {

    @Inject
    private Role selected;

    @EJB
    private RoleService bean;

    public RoleController() {
        super(Role.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        reList();
    }

    public Role getSelected() {
        return this.selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Role registro) {
        if (registro == null)
            this.selected = new Role();
        else
            this.selected = new Role(registro);
    }

    public void update() {
        if (reList())
            enviarMensagemSucesso("Dados atualizados");
    }

    private boolean reList() {
        try {
            this.list = this.bean.listarTodos();
            this.filtered = new ArrayList<Role>(this.list);
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            enviarMensagemErro(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public List<Role> getList() {
        if (this.list == null) {
            try {
                this.list = this.bean.listarTodos();
            } catch (DAOException e) {
                enviarMensagemErro(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return this.list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Role> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void persist() {
        try {
            if (this.selected.getId() != 0) {
                this.bean.alterar(this.selected);
                enviarMensagemSucesso("Registro alterado com sucesso");
            } else {
                this.bean.adicionar(this.selected);
                enviarMensagemSucesso("Registro adicionado com sucesso");
            }
            sucesso();
            reList();
        } catch (DAOException | ValidacaoException e) {
            enviarMensagemErro(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void delete() {
        try {
            this.bean.excluir(this.selected);
            reList();
            enviarMensagemSucesso("Registro removido com sucesso!");
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            enviarMensagemErro(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

There a related question, but I'm not using ui:repeat or c:forEach tags: [JSF updates view just on second request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304336/jsf-updates-view-just-on-second-request)

Comment: PrimeFaces Extension upgraded to 3.2.0, removed PrimeFaces Mobile, migrated from `@ManagedBean` to `@Named`, now Im using wildfly 9.0.1, just to upgrade mojarra to 2.2.11, and the problem persists.

Comment: What if you use the new namespaces? Like here: https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/

Comment: Namespaces updated and the problem persists, removed all "ui" tags, using a simple page, and the problem persists.

Comment: There is a `h:head` tag in the `composite` and no `body`. I would expect that the ``h:head` is somewhere on the same level than the `body` tag. Check the `composite` is not included more than once....just an idea. But it would be strange that it works/not works with different PF versions.